# Error in css-loader building Angular 4 app for production

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I can compile and build an application using '`ng build`', but when I try to run '`ng build --prod --aot=false`' to build it for production, I get a really confusing error, which is:

> devrep@dev-laptop:~/Documents/projects/FWP$ ng build --prod
>   --aot=false
>        11% building modules 9/14 modules 5 active ...font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.cssNode#moveTo was deprecated.
>   Use Container#append.
>       Date: 2017-12-21T12:09:04.162Z
>       Hash: 4aab95fe772649d00bd9
>       Time: 64798ms
>       chunk {0} polyfills.87365c933937cb2f588a.bundle.js (polyfills) 65.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
>       chunk {1} main.7c8cba86955be3d0b56d.bundle.js (main) 687 kB [initial] [rendered]
>       chunk {2} styles.6794b28885d6e9fad13b.bundle.css (styles) 170 kB [initial] [rendered]
>       chunk {3} vendor.e43732721f7d20b3cde5.bundle.js (vendor) 771 kB [initial] [rendered]
>       chunk {4} inline.d266a3c997900449849a.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
>
> ```
> ERROR in ./src/app/integralui/css/integralui.module.css
> Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './.' in
> ```
>
> '/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css'
>           at factoryCallback (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:276:40)
>           at factory (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:235:20)
>           at resolver (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:60:20)
>           at asyncLib.parallel (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:127:20)
>           at /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3861:9
>           at /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:421:16
>           at iteratorCallback (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:996:13)
>           at /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
>           at /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3858:13
>           at resolvers.normal.resolve (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:119:22)
>           at onError (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:65:10)
>           at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>           at runAfter (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
>           at innerCallback (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
>           at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>           at next (/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
>        @ ./src/app/integralui/css/integralui.module.css
>        @ multi ./src/styles.css ./src/assets/zurb-foundation/foundation-prototype.min.css
>   ./src/assets/fwcIcons-font/css/fwcIcons.css
>   ./src/assets/fwcMenuIcons-font/css/fwcMenuIcons.css
>   ./src/app/integralui/css/integralui.module.css
>   ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
>   ./node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css
>       ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","plugins":[null,null,null,{"version":"5.2.18","plugins":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"postcssPlugin":"cssnano","postcssVersion":"5.2.18"}],"sourceMap":false}!./src/app/integralui/css/integralui.grid-default.css
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './.' in '/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css'
>       resolve './.' in '/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css'
>         using description file: /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app/integralui/css)
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>         after using description file: /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app/integralui/css)
>           using description file: /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app/integralui/css)
>             no extension
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css is not a file
>             .ts
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css.ts doesn't
>   exist
>             .js
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css.js doesn't
>   exist
>             as directory
>               existing directory
>                 using path: /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css/index
>                   using description file: /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app/integralui/css/index)
>                     no extension
>                       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                       /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css/index
>   doesn't exist
>                     .ts
>                       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                       /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css/index.ts
>   doesn't exist
>                     .js
>                       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                       /home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css/index.js
>   doesn't exist
>       [/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css]
>       [/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css.ts]
>       [/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css.js]
>       [/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css/index]
>       [/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css/index.ts]
>       [/home/devrep/Documents/projects/FWP/src/app/integralui/css/index.js]
>        @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","plugins":[null,null,null,{"version":"5.2.18","plugins":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"postcssPlugin":"cssnano","postcssVersion":"5.2.18"}],"sourceMap":false}!./src/app/integralui/css/integralui.grid-default.css
>   6:9668-9682
>        @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","plugins":[null,null,null,{"version":"5.2.18","plugins":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],"postcssPlugin":"cssnano","postcssVersion":"5.2.18"}],"sourceMap":false}!./src/app/integralui/css/integralui.grid.css
>        @ ./src/app/integralui/css/integralui.module.css
>        @ multi ./src/styles.css ./src/assets/zurb-foundation/foundation-prototype.min.css
>   ./src/assets/fwcIcons-font/css/fwcIcons.css
>   ./src/assets/fwcMenuIcons-font/css/fwcMenuIcons.css
>   ./src/app/integralui/css/integralui.module.css
>   ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
>   ./node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css

I've tried some solutions that I found on Google, like copying all the CSS files into the '`assets`' folder or updating the `Angular CLI` bit it didn't make a change. I can't understand what's complaining about and what's that `'./.'` module that can't be found.

Any clue?

I'm using `node 9.3.0`, `npm 5.6.0` and `Angular CLI 1.6.2` with `Angular 4.4.6`.

Thanks!

Comment: hard to tell but it may be with your webpack configuration.
https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/564#issuecomment-244360993

Answer (score 2):

The problem was an incorrect CSS file in one of the components used in the application. And it was this single line:

```
background: url('') no-repeat 0 0;
```

We left the URL empty by mistake and it seems that the compiler couldn't build the app for production (although it compiles perfectly for development).

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Please update "@angular/cli" to "1.7.3"

1. npm remove @angular/cli
2. npm cache clean --force
3. npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.3

Still stuck then update your package.json with

```
@angular/cli": "1.7.3"
```

Then run npm install

Tested and working for me